# Angular 2 and webpack, import images with [src] syntax

Tags: angular, webpack

Im trying to import a picture in my angular 2 application like this:

```
<img *ngIf="person.status" [src]="{{IMAGE_URL}}" width="20" height="20" />
```

But when I use the [src] tag webpack doesn't include the picture in the output files of my bundled project. If I include the picture in the following way, everything works as expected.

```
<img *ngIf="person.status" src=require('IMAGE_URL') width="20" height="20" />
```

My webpack config looks like this(it's based on the webpack tutorial found in the angular 2 offical docs):

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    'polyfills': './app/polyfills.ts',
    'vendor': './app/vendor.ts',
    'app': './app/main.ts'
  },

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.ts']
  },

  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/,
        loaders: ['ts', 'angular2-template-loader']
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loader: 'html'
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg|woff|woff2|ttf|eot|ico)$/,
        loader: 'file?name=./assets/[name].[hash].[ext]'
      },
      {
        test:/\.scss$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader:'style!css!sass'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style', 'css?sourceMap')
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        include: helpers.root('src', 'app'),
        loader: 'raw'
      },
      {
        test:/\.json$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader:'json'
      }
    ]
  },

  plugins: [
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      name: ['app', 'vendor', 'polyfills']
    }),

    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'app/index.html'
    })
  ]
};
```

The reason why I want to use [src] is that the picture is changing dynamically during runtime and the url has to be able to change. Do anybody know how I can configure webpack to include pictures imported in my application with the [src] tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [webpack not able to import images( using express and angular2 in typescript)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36148639/webpack-not-able-to-import-images-using-express-and-angular2-in-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

Put the require() statement in your component file:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.IMAGE_URL = require('../../public/images/' + this.imageName + '.png');
}
```

then your can write your html the same way:

```
<img *ngIf="person.status" [src]="{{IMAGE_URL}}" width="20" height="20" />
```